# Python/Pandas : Accessing second level index labels limited to that of a particular label in first level?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-index DataFrame, with two levels.
I would like to have the list of all labels in the second level, given a label in the 1st level.

I succeed to do it this way.

```
import pandas as pd

arrays = [[1, 1, 2, 2], ['red', 'blue', 'velvet', 'grey']]
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('number', 'color'))
test = pd.DataFrame([[10,11],[20,21],[30,31], [40, 41]], index = midx, columns = ['First','Second'])

test
>>>               First  Second
    number color
    1      red       10      11
           blue      20      21
    2      velvet    30      31
           grey      40      41

# I want all labels in second level related to label '1' from first level.
test.loc[(1,),:].index
>>> Index(['red', 'blue'], dtype='object', name='color')

'red' in test.loc[(1,),:].index
>>> True
```

Is there any recommended way to do this, instead of `test.loc[(1,),:].index`?
(not sure it really is the most efficient / fastest way to do)

Thanks for any advice!
Bests,

Comment: You can simply write `test.loc[1].index` as well.

Comment: Should be fine. Index based selection is pretty fast. In general you can use `pd.IndexSlice` to form the slices when it's more complicated, or on something that isn't the outer most level. There's also `test.xs(1, axis=0, level='number')` to select subframes from the MultiIndex

Comment: Thanks both of you! Ok, I will simplify as suggested by @jfaccioni. Thanks again!